# Solspace User "remove_photo" with link instead of input button?

Tags: solspace, solspace-user, profile-edit

Using Solspace User and the {exp:user:edit} form, is it possible to to create an HTML links that has the same function as the button:

```
<input type="submit" name="remove_photo" value="Remove Current Photo?" />
```

I can't achieve the styling I want using an input button element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key for the avatar to be removed is to submit form data for "remove_photo". This means that you need an HTML form field for this to work. Hyperlinks are not form fields.

You can, however, trigger the form submission with a value "remove_photo" by using javascript/jQuery. The "remove_photo" field can be a hidden field as well. For example, if you had:

```
{exp:user:edit form:class="user_edit"}
    <a href="#" class="remove_photo">Remove Photo</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="remove_photo" value="Remove Current Photo?" />
{/exp:user:edit}
```

You could use a script like this, for example:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $("a.remove_photo").click(function () {
        $("form.user_edit").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks for the very helpful answer.